# Moving Site Collection to a different Web Application

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, web-application

I have been configuring a SP 2013 site, and I have a My Site Host Site Collection on its own Web Application. But now I find out I can't use two distinct URLs (our **"main"** site, **portal.company.com** may still exist but I can't also have **my.company.com**), so I need to move the My Site Host over to the portal Web Application.  Is this possible?  What are my options here?

Comment: what you want, move the all mysites to new web applications and update the MySite Host location?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE What I need is to move the My Site Host SC so that its URL begins with portal.company.com and not my.company.com

Comment: what is your current MySite host location? portal or my? and you want your mysites start from Portal.company.com, correct?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE My current My Site Host SC is located at `my`.  And yes, "you want your mysites start from Portal.company.com"

Comment: it is not best practice to use same web application for Mysite and Non-mysite...but if you want see my anwser.

Comment: It is not only not a best practice it will generate a health issue in Central Admin. u will get the following message: "Validate the My Site Host and Individual My Sites are on a dedicated Web application and separate URL Domain"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to change the mysite Host location to new web application(portal.company.com) and in this process you have to perform two things.

1. update your user profile services for mysite host location, Create Managed Path, enable self services site creation,
2. Now move all existing MySite collection from existing web app to new webApp.

**To move Site collections**

You can detach the database from existing(my.company.com) web application and reattach to portal.company.com web app.

Or u can take the backup of Site collections(My Site) one by one and restore it to portal web app.

helpful http://amjadk.wordpress.com/2012/12/22/mysites-and-the-mysite-host-in-sharepoint-2013/

But on the side note, it is highly recommended keep the mysite host web application separate.

> Although you can use an existing web application to host these site
>   collections, we recommend that you use a dedicated web application to
>   improve performance and manageability.My Sites require that a site
>   collection exist at the web application root (which is displayed as /
>   in the user interface). Without this, you will receive a message that
>   states that there is no site collection at the root when you try to
>   enable self-service site creation for the web application. Because we
>   recommend that you use a dedicated web application to host My Sites,
>   you should use the root path for the My Site host collection unless
>   you have a specific requirement to create the site collection deeper
>   in the uniform resource locator (URL) path.

Read this technet for more understanding. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262500(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Your answer here appears to be helpful - but lacks necessary detail.  "update your user profile services for mysite host location" - I think I know what you mean there... "Create Managed Path" - do you mean add a new managed path?  What are Best Practices here?  Should I expect errors to happen before everything is completed?  I don't know what to expect in any of these intermediate steps.

Comment: if you read both links i mentioned in my response, 1st will explain about the steps what to do....2nd will explain why it is not recommended.

Comment: After doing some reading, it seems like the best thing to do would be to move the whole web app to a new URL.  Or maybe "Extend" the web app so it is accessible from another URL?

Comment: extending the existing web again not good idea becuase same web app for mysite and non mysites...

Comment: "becuase same web app for mysite and non mysites" - not sure what you're saying here.  Extending a web app creates another IIS site, but does not duplicate/move/copy content.

Comment: it extend the same web app and yes create new IIS site ...but both sites shared same content databases. that's what i am saying

Comment: Sorry - so I'm missing why then both sites sharing the same content db is a bad idea.

Comment: If you want to expose the same content in a Web application to different types of users by using additional URLs or authentication methods, you can extend an existing Web application into a new zone. When you extend the Web application into a new zone, you create a separate Internet Information Services (IIS) Web site to serve the same content, but with a unique URL and authentication type.http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261698(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is not recommended for obvious reasons, if you do want to move them into the portal web app, you can do the following:

- create an explicit managed path under the portal web app called "my"
- create a mysite host SC at that location
- create a wildcard managed path under portal called "my/personal"
- in the User Profile Service App, change the location of the mysite host to portal.company.com/my
- on the same page, change the path of personal site to portal.company.com/my/personal
- Backup All existing mysites from old separate web app using Backup-SPSite (using powershell, `Get-SPWebApplication <url> | Get-SPSite | Foreach-Object { $_ | Backup-SPSite -Path "<backupfolder>\$($_.Title).bak"`
- Restore all MySites in new location (with powershell loop through all backup files: `Get-ChildItem <path to backup files> | Foreach-Object { Restore-SPSite -Identity <new url> -Path $_.FullName }`
- Change the personalsite property for each user profile to point to new location of that user's restored my site.
- Enable Self-service site creation on the portal web app