# Is possible to publish OneDrive for Business to internet only?

Tags: onedrive-for-business

I'd like to know, in SharePoint Server 2016 on-premises deployment with OneDrive for Business configured in My Sites, how to allow the external users to access the shared files? I mean, only the shared files, not the whole SharePoint.

I don't have test environment right now, so kindly suggest me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a separate WebApplication which hosts your MySites?

Comment: @MHeld good point, and I haven't, I have two frontend servers and that's a good idea to separate.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not have a separate WebApplication for MySites, your options are limited without modifying central things on your environment:

- [Moving Mysites to new WebApplication](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116422/moving-site-collection-to-a-different-web-application).
- External sharing via [WebApplicationProxy](https://www.brightstarr.com/sharepoint-technology-and-application-insights/blog/securely-publishing-sharepoint-externally-using-web-application-proxy). This brings a lot of questions about managing external users.

You should consider [OneDrive for Business](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-external-sharing-ee8b91c5-05ec-44c2-9796-78fa27ec8425) in Office365 as this already might have all Features you need.